# Modifying route names - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models (Book and Review) and 2 controllers(Books and Reviews). A book has many Reviews and Reviews belong to a Book.

Routes:

```
resources :books
```

In the show controller i have:

```
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
@reviews = @book.review
```

1) This results in a route of:

```
https://localhost:8080/books/1
```

I want this to be:

```
https://localhost:8080/harry_potter/reviews
```

where name of the book = Harry Potter

2) And when i set up the reviews page i want the route to be:

```
https://localhost:8080/harry_potter/reviews/new_york_times
```

instead of

```
https://localhost:8080/reviews/1
```

where name of reviewer = New York Times

Comment: If you want to write your own methods: http://code-worrier.com/blog/custom-slugs-in-rails/

Comment: If you want to just use a gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: @LannyBose thank you for the links! just what i needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look up [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), there's a [good RailsCast about it here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid):

[image]

---

Essentially, what you need is to be able to handle [*slugs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug) in your system.

IE instead of passing an `id` (`primary_key`), you identify the record with another identifier (in our case a "slug").

`Friendly ID` facilitates this - here's how:

```
#app/models/book.rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyID
   friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end
```

This gives you the ability to use the following in your controller:

```
#app/controllers/books_controller.rb
class BooksController < ApplicationController
   def show 
       @book = Book.find params[:id] #-> the route passes the "slug" as "id" still
   end
end

#config/routes.rb
resources :books #-> url.com/books/:id -> you can pass the "slug" to ID
```

--

You'll [have to add a column](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#rails-quickstart) to your tables you wish to use `friendly_id` on (in your case `books` and `reviews`):

```
$ rails g migration AddSlugToBooks

#db/migrate/add_slug_to_books______.rb
class AddSlugToBooks
   def change
      add_column :books, :slug, :string
      add_column :reviews, :slug, :string
   end
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`

After that (important), you need to update your current records. To do this, you should use the following:

```
$ rails c
$ Book.find_each(&:save)
$ Review.find_each(&:save)
```

This will get the routes working with your slugs, allowing you to call the likes of:

```
book_path("harry_potter")
```

---

**Nested Resources**

As an added note, you'll want to look up a routing principle called [*nested resources*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Using these, you'll be able to employ the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :books do
   resources :reviews, only: [:index, :show] #-> url.com/books/:book_id/reviews
end
```

This will give you the ability to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
   def index 
      @book = Book.find params[:id]
      @reviews = @book.reviews
   end
end
```

Thus you'll end up with the following: `url.com/books/harry_potter/reviews`

Comment: Thank you so much, it is exactly what i needed!

Comment: Niiice! For future reference, you may wish to accept either this answer or the other so people know which is correct

Comment: Done, new to stackoverflow so didn't know that the feature existed.

Answer (score 0):

I have been digging around and i think i found the answer to the first question:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-vanity-urls-in-rails